# SQL distinct values in multiple tables

Tags: sql, postgresql

I am a bit stuck on some SQL work. Basically, I have 3 different tables, looking something like this: (NOTE: The "Number" is supposed to be the ID number of a book, numbers repeating means it's the same book. I changed it to be like this for the sake of simplicity.)

Table A:

```
Number Name    Surname
1      Bob     Bobinson
1      Paul    Paulster
2      Simon   Simones
3      Anton   Antonio
etc.
```

Table B:

```
Number   Book
1        Taken
1        
1        
2        Taken
2        Taken
3        
3        Taken
3        Taken
etc.
```

Table C:

```
Number      Pages
1           245
2           147
3           512
etc.
```

What I need to do is for each different Name and Surname count the number of times their number repeats in Table B and then count the total page number for each.
The answer table should look like this:

```
Bob Bobinson 3 735
Paul Paulster 3 735
Simon Simones 2 294
Anton Antonio 3 1536
```

I tried something like this:

```
SELECT Name, Surname, Count(A.Number = B.Number) FROM A, B, C;
```

Yeah, I'll be honest: I have absolutely no clue what it needs to look like. I tried implementing WHILE A.Number = B.Number afterwards, but it doesn't work out for me. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

P.S. The "Taken" is for later, for checking which number has the most takens.

Comment: Tip of the day: switch to modern, explicit `JOIN` syntax!

Comment: Why do Bob and Paul share the same ID?

Comment: @jarlh They are co-authors of a book, the numbers pointing to distinct books, but I changed that here for the sake of making the tables easier to read.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should get what you want:

```
select A.Name, B.Surname, count(*), C.Pages
  from TableA
       Join TableB on A.Number = B.Number
       Join TableC on A.Number = C.Number
group by A.Name, B.Surname, C.Pages;
```

Alternatively you could do it with a sub-query if it makes subsequent alterations easier, though generally speaking these don't perform as well:

```
select A.Name, B.Surname,
       (select count(*)
          from TableBB
         where B.Number = A.Number) As CNT,
       C.Pages
  from TableA
       Join TableC on A.Number = C.Number;
```

Comment: It has indeed. Thank you! I really need to get used to using Join.

Comment: No problem.  You may already know this, but if you're going to try and work out how many of each books are taken next you should be able to do it by summing a case statement i.e. sum(case when B.Book = 'Taken' then 1 else 0 end).